# PHP: from HTML form input to printable PDF

Tags: php, pdf

I have a simple page containing PHP code that permits users to input values and by hitting a button, calculations are performed and results output in few html text fields.

I would like to have a print version, i.e. users enter values and by hitting another button, a PDF file is generated with basically some formatted text and calculated values so they can print it.

Is it possible to do it with pure PHP? I am pretty novice, but still better then java where I am clueless.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at the PDF functions in the PHP manaual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdf.examples-basic.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Of course, I've already checked in the manual, but to be honest I went pretty fast through and didn't find anything concrete. Since I'm novice, I guess I will must go deep and make hundreds of tests. It's just that I though there was some kind of simple solution. Anyway, thanks again.